# Using tal:content and getting <br/>

Tags: php, zend-framework, template-tal, phptal

I am using Zend Framework with PHPTAL templates for view sites.

Problem is that I have `<span>` that contains `tal:content = value`. Value is the field (string) from database which contains html tag `<br/>`. When I try to get this field from db, I don't get new line but hardcoded `<br/>` string.

Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPTAL automatically escapes all variables.

You need to use [structure keyword](http://phptal.org/manual/en/#tales-structure) to disable the escaping.